# Assign unique ID to each data.frame element in a list

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, unique

I have a list of many (spatial) data.frames. I want to add a column to each data.frame that has an ID equivalent to the list index ID (i.e., every row in each individual data.frame's new column will have the same ID).

I think I have to use some apply function along with cbind, but I do not know how to format it for each element in a list (especially of Spatial data.frames elements). Please help!

Here is some example code to work with:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1 = c(1, 2, 3), y2 = c(4, 5, 6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1 = c(3, 2, 1), y2 = c(6, 5, 4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)
```

I want to end up with the following:

```
[[1]]
  y1 y2 unique.id
1  1  4  1
2  2  5  1
3  3  6  1

[[2]]
  y1 y2 unique.id
1  3  6  2
2  2  5  2
3  1  4  2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
newlist <- Map(cbind,my.list, unique.id = (1:length(my.list)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by `mapply` -

```
> mapply(function(x, y) "[<-"(x, "ID", value = y) , my.list, 1:length(my.list), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

**OR**

```
> mapply(cbind, my.list, "SampleID"=1:length(my.list), SIMPLIFY=F)

[[1]]

$`1`
  y1 y2 ID
1  1  4  1
2  2  5  1
3  3  6  1

$`2`
  y1 y2 ID
1  3  6  2
2  2  5  2
3  1  4  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replace`.

```
lapply(seq_along(my.list), 
       function(x) setNames(replace(my.list[[x]], ncol(my.list[[x]]) + 1, x), 
                            c(names(my.list[[x]]), "unique.id")))
# [[1]]
#   y1 y2 unique.id
# 1  1  4         1
# 2  2  5         1
# 3  3  6         1
# 
# [[2]]
#   y1 y2 unique.id
# 1  3  6         2
# 2  2  5         2
# 3  1  4         2
```

Or slightly shorter

```
lapply(seq_along(my.list), 
       function(x) cbind(my.list[[x]], unique.id=x))
[[1]]
  y1 y2 unique.id
1  1  4         1
2  2  5         1
3  3  6         1

[[2]]
  y1 y2 unique.id
1  3  6         2
2  2  5         2
3  1  4         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `for` loop

```
for (i in seq_along(my.list)) {
  my.list[[i]] <- data.frame(my.list[[i]], "unique.id" = i)
}

> my.list
[[1]]
  y1 y2 unique.id
1  1  4         1
2  2  5         1
3  3  6         1

[[2]]
  y1 y2 unique.id
1  3  6         2
2  2  5         2
3  1  4         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Mike and Rushabh have:

```
mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
  x$unique.id <- y
  x
}, x = my.list, y = 1:length(my.list), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can collapse the list into a single *dataframe* with an **id**, then *split* again:

```
library(data.table)

x <- rbindlist(my.list, idcol = "unique.id")
#    unique.id y1 y2
# 1:         1  1  4
# 2:         1  2  5
# 3:         1  3  6
# 4:         2  3  6
# 5:         2  2  5
# 6:         2  1  4
my.list <- split(x, x$unique.id)
# $`1`
#    unique.id y1 y2
# 1:         1  1  4
# 2:         1  2  5
# 3:         1  3  6
# 
# $`2`
#    unique.id y1 y2
# 1:         2  3  6
# 2:         2  2  5
# 3:         2  1  4
```