# R - assign unique ID to each Spatial_DataFrame element in a list

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, geospatial

I have a list of many `SpatialLinesDataFrames`. I want to add a column to each SLDF that has an ID equivalent to the list index ID (i.e., every row in each individual SLDFs new column will have the same ID). I would like the solution to be workable to any kind of `sp` Spatial DataFrame object (polygons, points, etc).

Based on a solution for simple data.frames ([Assign unique ID to each data.frame element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55638951/r-assign-unique-id-to-each-data-frame-element-in-a-list)), I tried this with the following example code:

```
library(raster)
#create list of single-feature `SpatialLineDataFrame`
l1 <- cbind(c(0,3), c(0,3))
l2 <- cbind(c(0, 13), c(0, 1))
l3 <- cbind(c(0, 24), c(0,22.5))
l4 <- cbind(c(0, 1), c(0,13))
l5 <- cbind(c(0, 6), c(0,6))
Sldf <- spLines(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, attr=data.frame(lineID=1:5))

#make individual list elements
sldfl <- list()
sldfl[[1]] <- Sldf[1,]
sldfl[[2]] <- Sldf[2,]
sldfl[[3]] <- Sldf[3,]
sldfl[[4]] <- Sldf[4,]
sldfl[[5]] <- Sldf[5,]

#attempt to add new column with unique index id
newlist <- Map(cbind,sldfl, unique.id = (1:length(sldfl)))
```

I want the column name to be "unique.id" and the same for all elements, but the results are element-specific and not the name I specify (i.e., X1L, X2L, etc) as follows:

```
[[1]]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 0, 3, 0, 3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 2
names       : lineID, X1L 
value       :      1,   1 

[[2]]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 0, 13, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 2
names       : lineID, X2L 
value       :      2,   2
```

But I want this:

```
[[1]]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 0, 3, 0, 3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 2
names       : lineID, unique.id 
value       :      1,   1 

[[2]]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 0, 13, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 2
names       : lineID, unique.id 
value       :      2,   2
```

Comment: What package is `spLines` from? Doesn't seem to be in `sp`...

Comment: Also, please show how to rename with `unique.id` on **one** sp data frame? We can then help you iterate across all in a list.

Comment: sorry @Gregor - raster::spLines. Will edit code accordingly

Comment: @Parfait I do not know how to rename with one sp data frame other than to call a single specific list element, e.g., newlist1 <- Map(cbind,sldfl[[1]], unique.id = (1:length(sldfl[[1]])))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple for loop.

```
for (i in seq_along(sldfl)) {
  sldfl[[i]]@data = cbind(sldfl[[i]]@data, unique.id = i)
}

sldfl
# [[1]]
# class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
# features    : 1 
# extent      : 0, 3, 0, 3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# variables   : 2
# names       : lineID, unique.id 
# value       :      1,         1 
# 
# [[2]]
# class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
# features    : 1 
# extent      : 0, 13, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : NA 
# variables   : 2
# names       : lineID, unique.id 
# value       :      2,         2 
# ...
```

The issue with the `Map` approach you tried is that `cbind` doesn't work for adding columns to a `SpatialLinesDataFrame`, you need to use `cbind` explicitly on  `@data` slot. We could use `Map`, but I find the explicit for loop clearer, especially if you want to modify the object in place.

```
newlist <- Map(function(x, y) cbind(x@data, unique.id = y), sldfl,  1:length(sldfl))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better way to do what Gregor suggested

```
for (i in seq_along(sldfl)) {
  sldfl[[i]]$unique.id <- i
}
```